# Is the given condition necessary for $HK$ to be isomorphic to $H\times K$?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism, direct-product

> 1. $H \triangleleft G,K \triangleleft G, H \cap K=e$, then, $HK$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $HK$ isomorphic to $H\times K$, where, $\triangleleft$ denotes normal subgroup.
> 2. If $G$ isomorphic to $H\times K$, then, $H \triangleleft G,K \triangleleft G, H \cap K=e$ and $HK$ isomorphic to $H×K$

From 1, we get the conditions on H and K is sufficient for HK to be isomorphic to H×K. Are the above conditions necessary?

**My attempt**:

I have been given that H and K are subgroups of G such that HK forms a subgroup of G and $HK$ isomorphic to $H\times K$. I need to check whether this implies $H$ and $K$ are normal in $G$ and intersection is identity. From 2, we have if we replace $G$ by $HK$, $H$ and $K$ are normal in $HK$ and intersection is identity. But this does not necessarily imply $H$ and $K$ normal in $G$. But I cannot find a counterexample to prove this.

Comment: $H$ and $K$ are normal since elements of $H$ and $K$ commute, so that the conjugation action of $H$ on $K$ (and vice versa) is trivial.

Comment: Can you please work on the wording of this question? You first give two statements (1) and (2), then you say "from (1) we get the condition is sufficient". What condition? (1)? Sufficient for what? For (2)? Are you trying to prove that the statement (2) implies (1)? Or something else?

Comment: How are you given $HK$ is isomorphic to $H\times K$? That looks like a conclusion in each of $1$ and $2$.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please have a look

Comment: Trivially not. Take any group $G$ with a subgroup $L$ which is not normal. Now take $H=L, K=\{e\}$.

Comment: @Stinking And in non-trivial case?